# Conciseness in constructing array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am doing some kind of recursion, where I calculate left and right sides of array. I have working code, but wonder if this could be written more concisely. Here is code:

```
left = calculate(x[0])
right = calculate(x[1])
a = Array.new(0)
a << left
a << right
self(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
self(x[0..1].map{|e| calculate(e)})
```

If x has only two elements, you can omit `[0..1]`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be written as:

```
left = calculate(x[0])
right = calculate(x[1])
self([left, right])
```

You could inline the `left` and `right` variables as well, but I think it would make the code less intention revealing.

Answer (score 1):

```
self(x[0..1].map{|e| calculate(e)})
```

can be rewritten

```
self(x[0..1].map(&method(:calculate)))
```

You expend three more characters this way, but you'd be ahead if `e` was three characters long or longer.